# Call a clientsideevent from another clientsideevent

Tags: asp.net, gridview, client-side, webforms

ASP.net(C#), VS2010, Win 7.

New to WebDev, so this might be a simple syntax thing but here it goes...

Long story short I have to force a postback on a GridView that shows attachments I upload using an ASPxUploadControl.  I put the GridView inside an ASPxCallbackPanel and am trying to get my GridView to update on the page after an attachment is uploaded using ASPxCallbackPanel.PerformCallback();

Here's the Upload control, in its' ClientSideEvent is where I'm trying to call the clientSideEvent from the Button shown below.  Just trying to force a button click really, but I tried doing it from the code-behind but that didn't work.  Any help would be appreciated!

```
 <dxuc:ASPxUploadControl ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" 
        ClientInstanceName="uploader"  
        ShowAddRemoveButtons="False" 
        ShowUploadButton="True" 
        AddUploadButtonsHorizontalPosition="Center" 
        AddUploadButtonsVerticalPosition="Top" FileInputCount="1" 
        UploadMode="Advanced" 
        OnFileUploadComplete="UploadControl_FileUploadComplete"

        Size="30">
        <ClientSideEvents FileUploadComplete="function(s, e) { Button1.Click; }" />
        <%-- <AdvancedModeSettings EnableMultiSelect="True" />  "does not have public property named "advancedModeSettings" version is too old--%>
        <ValidationSettings
            AllowedFileExtensions=".doc,.pdf,.xls,.txt,.jpeg,.jpg,.gif,.png,.oft,.htm,.html,.mht,.rtf,.zip"
            MaxFileSize="5242880"
            FileDoesNotExistErrorText="This file can't be found." 
            GeneralErrorText="Custom file uploading fails due to an external error that doesn't relate to the ASPxUploadControl's functionality" 
            MaxFileSizeErrorText="Size of the uploaded file exceeds maximum file size"> 
            <ErrorStyle ForeColor="Red"/>

       </ValidationSettings> 
     </dxuc:ASPxUploadControl>
```

Here is the GridView as well as a button I made that successfully refreshes the grid.

```
<div>
        <dxe:ASPxButton ID="ASPxButton1" runat="server" ClientInstanceName="Button1" Text="Reload Panel" AutoPostBack="False">
            <ClientSideEvents Click="function(s, e) {ASPxCallbackPanel1.PerformCallback(); e.processOnServer = true;}" />
        </dxe:ASPxButton>
         <dx:ASPxCallbackPanel ID="ASPxCallbackPanel1" runat="server" 
             ClientInstanceName="ASPxCallbackPanel1" Width="492px" 
            Height="100%">
            <PanelCollection>
            <dx:PanelContent runat="server">   

                <asp:GridView ID="gvAttachment" SkinID="grid" runat="server" Width="98%"

                OnRowDataBound="AttachmentControl_OnRowDataBound"

                meta:resourcekey="gvAttachResource1"
                PagerSettings-FirstPageText="<%$ Resources:CommonControlText,FirstPageText %>"
                PagerSettings-LastPageText="<%$ Resources:CommonControlText,LastPageText %>"
                PagerSettings-PreviousPageText="<%$ Resources:CommonControlText,PreviousPageText %>"
                PagerSettings-NextPageText="<%$ Resources:CommonControlText,NextPageText %>" 
                   AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                <EmptyDataRowStyle CssClass="emptyData" />
                <EmptyDataTemplate>
                    <table class="usercontroldetail container_table">
                        <tr>
                            <td class="tdlayout">
                                <asp:Label ID="Localize1" runat="server">
                                    <%= Placeholder %>
                                </asp:Label>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </EmptyDataTemplate>
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="AtchmtId" HeaderText="Attachment ID" 
                        visible = "false" meta:resourcekey="BoundFieldResource1">
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField  DataField ="FileNm" HeaderText="File Name" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="UsrNm" HeaderText="Uploaded By" 
                         />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="AtchmtDt" HeaderText="Date" 
                         />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="FileSizeCnt" HeaderText="File Size" 
                         />
                    <asp:TemplateField AccessibleHeaderText="Actions" HeaderText="Actions">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <div style="text-align:center;">
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="btnDelete" Visible="False" runat="server"
                                    ToolTip="Delete Selected Attachment"
                                    OnClick="btnDelete_Click"
                                    Text="Delete" CausesValidation="True" DisableOnSubmit="True" Group="" 
                                    meta:resourcekey="btnDeleteResource1" />
                                <asp:Label ID="lblPipe" runat="server" Text="|" />
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="btnView" Visible="False" runat="server"
                                    ToolTip="View Selected Attachment"
                                    OnClick="btnView_Click"
                                    Text="View" CausesValidation="True" DisableOnSubmit="True" Group="" 
                                    meta:resourcekey="btnViewResource1" />
                            </div>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <ItemStyle Wrap="false" />
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>

        <%--<PagerSettings FirstPageText="First" LastPageText="Last" NextPageText="Next &gt;" PreviousPageText="&lt; Previous"></PagerSettings>--%>

                <RowStyle CssClass="row_odd" />
                <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="row_even" />
            </asp:GridView>
            </dx:PanelContent>
            </PanelCollection>
          </dx:ASPxCallbackPanel>
```

FYI: The GridView is getting the new attachment put in it. I'm just not seeing it on the page because the UploadControl only updates itself.

Edit:Figured it out just used the OnClick() method as below. Derp.  Forgot that the ASPx button inherited all the ASP buttons methods.  But now my original plan of making the button invisible seems to be foiled.  When Button1.OnClick() is called with the Visible property for the Button set to "false". it says Button1 is not defined.  Anyway around this?

```
<ClientSideEvents FileUploadComplete="function(s, e) { Button1.OnClick(); }" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right, you can manipulate the behavior of all update panels on page via property called [a updateMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.updatemode.aspx) (Conditional, Always). Changing one updatepanel will cause refreshing of all, if all have mode set to Always.